# Inconsistent information in Git (log vs. diff) about single file

Tags: git

I have encountered a problem running following git commands:

1. Diff between two branches for one file delivers clear information about existing differences:

   ```
   $ git diff --shortstat develop-2.2 feature/develop-2.2-Grouping -- coba.zaa.tools/coba.zaa.tools.resources/src/main/resources/workflows/processflow/statemachine.ftl

   1 file changed, 162 insertions(+), 24 deletions(-)
   ```
2. However a search for the commits with the differences delivers no results:

   ```
   $ git log --oneline develop-2.2...feature/develop-2.2-Grouping coba.zaa.tools/coba.zaa.tools.resources/src/main/resources/workflows/processflow/statemachine.ftl
   ```

Is it a right reasoning and if so is my repo corrupt? Is there any way to check a consistency of the repo (e.g. if all commits are same, then all files should be same)?

Comment: Is the `...` in the `git log` command intentional? I would think that would be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @TriskalJM yes, it is intentional. It should list all commits where changes were made to this file, that are present in one branch but do not exist in another.

Comment: Try it with `--full-history`, and if that  does produce results do it again with  `--graph --decorate` and post the results? I think you should be seeing results too.

Comment: You're looking for `git fsck`. That being said, your understanding of `...` is wrong (it is the symmetric difference, not the latter excluding those reachable from the former), but even so I would expect `..` to produce the same result. Nevertheless, this behavior does not seem to be indicative of Git file corruption; I would suggest using `..` (also maybe dropping the dots, since they're irrelevant here) and `--` with `git log` since unless you have a specific reason to suspect data corruption far more likely is that you're getting the Git usage wrong (a typo somewhere, perhaps).

Comment: @jthill that was great hint, thx, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--full-history` did the job.

I was able to find additional commits that were not listed in the standard `git log` output as listed above. I found a commit with resolved merge conflicts that changed the file. Thanks to @jthill for the hint.

However, what is the reason `git log` works this way beats me.